# Laravel : Self-contained package doing the same as django-admin?

Tags: model, laravel-4, django-admin, scaffolding

I'm banging my head trying to find a package which does the same as Django Admin in Python/Django (i.e. Users/Groups/Permissions AND registered models scaffolding), but for Laravel 4.

Currently I installed Syntara, but don't know whether it can register models to bind a scaffolding, or how.

How can I use Syntara to register model classes, or which alternative package can I use? (Perhaps someone providing an integration with Syntara, or an alternative to Syntara providing the same features + model scaffolding).